# Unresolved externals and some warnings while building the qt solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have Qt libraries 4.8.1 for Windows (VS 2010 ultimate) with Qt Visual Studio Add-in. This is my very simple app :

```
#include<qobject.h>
#include<qstring.h>
#include<memory>

class MyClass : public QObject{
Q_OBJECT

public:
MyClass( const QString &text, QObject *parent = 0 ) : m_text(text) {}

public slots:
void setText( const QString &text );

signals:
void textChanged( const QString& );

private:
QString m_text;
};

void MyClass::setText( const QString &text ){
if( m_text == text ) return;
m_text = text;
emit textChanged( m_text );
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> a(new MyClass("foo"));
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> b(new MyClass("bar"));

QObject::connect( a.get(), SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString&)),
b.get(), SLOT(setText(const QString&)) );
a->setText("changed");
}
```

> Errors I get related to unresolved externals :  Error 6   error LNK2001:
>   unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall
>   MyClass::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)"
>   (?qt_metacall@MyClass@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)
>
> Error 4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual
>   struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall MyClass::metaObject(void)const "
>   (?metaObject@MyClass@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
>
> Error 5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual
>   void * __thiscall MyClass::qt_metacast(char const *)"
>   (?qt_metacast@MyClass@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
>
> Error 3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: void
>   __thiscall MyClass::textChanged(class QString const &)" (?textChanged@MyClass@@IAEXABVQString@@@Z) referenced in function
>   "public: void __thiscall MyClass::setText(class QString const &)"
>   (?setText@MyClass@@QAEXABVQString@@@Z)

and two warnings :

> Warning   1   warning MSB8017: A circular dependency has been detected
>   while executing custom build commands for item
>   "GeneratedFiles\Debug\main.moc". This may cause incremental build to
>   work incorrectly.
>
> Warning   2   warning : No resources in
>   'C:\Users\Anonymous\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\qtWorld\qtWorld\qtworld.qrc'.

**I didn't use any qmake / nmake . They ain't required when you get latest Qt Visual Studio Add-in 1.1.11 (even Intellisense recognizes the keywords `slots:` `signals:`), right?**

**Now my questions :**

1. I heard many errors are resolved by just rebuilding the whole solution , why is that ?
2. Please explain why I get these errors in deep and their possible solutions.

p.s please be good at explanation, don't be rep whorer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have QObject class defined in cpp file then you should also include moc for that file.
For example your MyClass is defined in main.cpp then you should add

> ```
> #include "main.moc"
> ```

to end of your main.cpp file.

Thanks to @Tomma for providing the unexplained answer :P

Explanation why above code didn't work :

However, the moc is typically applied to header files only. Since your class definition is part of the main program file, the IDE does not recognize it.

Thanks to @koahnig for providing nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of your class is not defined, only declared. Same thing for the `textChanged()` method. At least that is what I see from the code that you posted. Define them and the error should go away.

Comment: moc is supposed to create the implementation for the signal textChanged()

Comment: `textChanged` is signal , how can define  it? . though I defined the constructor now it's still giving same warning and errors . Read my questions again please

Comment: Although I use the addon in Visual Studio I do not use the automated moc function (I am using CMake instead) so I am unsure how that works. If moc is being run you should have a moc_ file in your build folder somewhere that includes the implementation. I can not help at all with getting the addon to work.

Comment: I am also unable to help with the moc part, sorry.